# Is there any better tutorial to learn symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Although there is jobeet tutorial available but I am looking for a better tutorial to learn and understand Symfony 1.4. I tried my hands on jobeet tutorial but while following the tutorial I was lost somewhere in setting the route.yml. Can some one suggest me if there is better tutorial? [Thank you in advance]

Comment: The jobeet tutorial is actually one of the best tutorials I have seen for a framework.

Comment: @ilanco : I have also tried the Gentle Introduction. I was using codeigniter for my other projects

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the question where you're stuck? The routing in symfony is not very complex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original Symfony Book http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/ is still a really good resource. Some of the features are depreciated but conceptually it's a clear guide to the framework. I wish that it carried over to the 1.4 and 2.0 versions as it's a better single resource than all of the other individual ones.

The biggest areas of change are forms, ignore this section completely in the book and use: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/

And finally, the what's new tutorial covers all of the changes in detail. 
http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/whats-new

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Gentle Introduction](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/) ?